# is forkjoin run all observables simultaneously or one by one?

Tags: rxjs

here is the example

```
forkJoin(
 
  {
    google: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/google'),
    microsoft: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/microsoft'),
    users: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users')
  }
 )
 
 .subscribe(console.log);
```

There are three API calls in the forkjoin. I am confused about, is all API calls will run one by one. Or it runs all calls at the same time and waits for responses?

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you describe, `forkJoin` acts like `Promise.all` - **all calls are made at the same time** (not one by one), once all of them return, forkjoin will fire once with the return value for those calls, here is the definition from the official site:

> Accepts an Array of ObservableInput or a dictionary Object of ObservableInput and returns an Observable that emits either an array of values in the exact same order as the passed array, ...

Please note that if one these were an observable (e.g. interval), and it fired three times before the other two return, only the last value would be emitted

See picture below from the official site:
[image]